# How to clean by cronjob all logs file of mongoDB in kubernetes?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-cronjob

- I have an app that works by deployment service and communicates with the world with Nginx-Ingress-controller.
- This app is connected to the MongoDB database.
- I asked to create a cronjob that purges all MongoDB logs once daily at midnight.

"Add a CronJob to purge all MongoDB Logs once daily at midnight - we want to
start the day with clean logs!"

I used Helm to create the Nginx-INgress-controller, and for MongoDB as well.

Does someone know which commands I should add to the CronJob?

Thanks in advance. :)

The code:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

for MongoDB I used  I helm - artifact hub with the commands:

- helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
- helm install my-release bitnami/mongodb --values test-mongodb.yaml

- link for the repo- https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb.

The values I inserted into test-mongodb.yaml:

```
architecture: replicaset
replicaCount: 3
persistence:
    storageClass: "standard"
auth:
  rootPassword: password
  password: password
  database: echo
  username: koren
```

Comment: I don't know kubernetes but have a look at `logrotate`. Typically you do not delete log files. You archive them for a few days and then delete them.

Comment: Check also this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Just to make sure: your mongodb runs in a container? If so, does it use shared/persistent volumes?

Comment: I know it's not what happens in real life but this is what we asked to do in the course.
About the rotate log file link, I saw it already and have no clue how to use it in my scenario by the cron job as the said in the task:
"Add a CronJob to purge all MongoDB Logs once daily at midnight - we want to start the day with clean logs!"
Thank you !
@WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Thanks for the correction, changed it, yes my mongo DB runs in a pod that runs a container.
I check the template and it seems like it uses persistent volumes for each pod:
but I am not sure how to use them with the cron job.
@PawełGrondal

Comment: I would still recommend logrotate. By setting `rotate 0` old logfile gets deleted instead of archived.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the **logs** due to **Kubernetes** also store the **stdin** & **out** logs. Kubernetes auto manages the logs rotation however if your **application** or **mongoD** internally storing the Logs in **PVC** or **filesystem** you might need to rotate it **daily**.

Instead of configuring the special job for deleting the job you can just config **mongoD** to rotate the logs config file

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 5
  compress
  dateext
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
  notifempty
}
```

Example : https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/27/automating-mongodb-log-rotation/

However still if you wish to run the job for clearing the logs from **PVC** or **filesystem** you can create the **side car** container.

**Update**

i have not tested however you can create the simple code and run it as the Cronjob inside the Kubernetes, that **node JS or any script** will connect to **MongoDB** admin database and rotate the log simply.

```
db.adminCommand( { logRotate : server } )
```

Connect to DB and rotate the log document :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

I think it will be simple program will make a connection and run rotate query.

Comment: actually, this way of rotating the log file from MongoDB sounds much better, but we asked to do it with the cronjob.
"Add a CronJob to purge all MongoDB Logs once daily at midnight - we want to start the day with clean logs!"
I didn't succeed to use side car from the cronjob, but thanks for trying.

Comment: @korenlios i have updated asnwer please check.

Comment: @korenlios if you find answer helpful dont forget to upvote or it's works :) don't forget to update status.